# Using Google's Voided Purchases API, there are some orders that can't be found

Tags: google-play

Google Pay's [Voided Purchases API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.voidedpurchases/list) provides a list of orders associated with purchase transactions that have been voided by the user, and this API is available for one-time in-app orders and app subscriptions.

Using Google's Voided Purchases API, there are some orders that can't be found when querying, has anyone experienced this?

This part of the order, I confirm:

- The refunded order is not older than 30 days
- The order has been acknowledged
- The order was not refunded through the developer interface, it was refunded by the user, and there is no revoke option on that refund page.